# How to set a new value for data-url attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-ajaxq

Before page load:

```
<a data-url="htts://xyz@..." class="mybuttons"  data-type="facebook">
```

After: On page load using jquery I used to append new data-url

```
<a data-url="https://abc@..." class="mybuttons"  data-type="facebook">
```

Now when I want to share this new data url using facebook api then
    it show old url `https://xyz@...` in url bar.

I want new `data-url` to be shared.

I have successfully change the `data-url` using  `$(this).attr('data-url',value.url)`. What to do please help me out. Even my new `data-url` is not getting show in page source.

Answer (score 4):

In your line:

```
$(this).attr('data-url',value.url);
```

are you sure `this` refers to the right DOM object?

Try adding an id to the anchor:

```
<a id='face-url' data-url="htts://xyz@..." class="mybuttons"  data-type="facebook">
```

Then in your code, set the `data-url` attribute this way:

```
$('#face-url').data('url', value.url);
```

Now that you have set the attribute value, you have to **be sure** that the facebook API reads this attribute only **after you've changed it**

Comment: For that what I have to do if I want facebook api should read new data-url

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but I had this problem and I think that I have the solution
For me the solution was change the way to set data.

```
$(this).data('url', value.url);
```